# What's the easiest way to download and compile all wxWidgets samples?

Tags: makefile, wxwidgets

I have svn, I have gcc, and I have make.  What's the easiest command line way to download and compile all wxWidgets samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxiwdgets has a lot of great documentation on how to build things with different compilers.  Don't miss it.

There's also the wiki. http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... this is a case where Google should have probably been my first resort instead of SO.  http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/svn.htm